# CKAN - Binding session to database in test file

Tags: python, session, ckan

I’m attempting to test a CKAN extension that I wrote. Basically I want to test that a function given certain parameters, successfully queries the database and returns the correct data. However I’m getting this error:

**UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper|User|user, SQL expression or this Session**

Here's the test: 
import unittest
from ckanext.matcher import plugin

```
class MatcherPluginTest(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    # Create instances
    self.plugin_instance = plugin.MatcherPlugin()

def test_func_call(self):
    user_account = ’testUser'
    user_ckan = self.plugin_instance.get_ckanuser(user_account)
    self.assertEqual(user_ckan['display_name'], 'Shani Agent')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

From my research this error is as result of a session variable not being attached or bound to a database. So i tried creating a session as follows but I still get the same error as above:

```
    def setUp(self):
        self.plugin_instance = plugin.MatcherPlugin()
        self.engine = create_engine('postgresql://...')
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = self.Session()
    def test_func_call(self):
        user_account = ’testUser'
        user_ckan = self.session.add(self.plugin_instance.get_ckanuser(user_account))
        self.session.commit()
        self.assertEqual(user_ckan['display_name'], 'Shani Agent')
```

Here's the `get_ckanuser` function, that is called in the `test_func_call` test:

```
    def get_ckanuser(self, user):
      import ckan.model

      user_ckan = ckan.model.User.by_name(user)

      # If the user exists, return user dictionary, else, return None
      if user_ckan:
          user_dict = toolkit.get_action('user_show')(data_dict={'id': user_ckan.id})
          return user_dict
      else:
          return None
```

Is there a way to bind the session to the database in the test file?

Answer (score 0):

The database session and general Pylons necessities are set-up by the nosetests Pylons plugin. So you need to use nosetests and use its `--with-pylons=../ckan/test-core.ini` parameter.

The docs for this are here: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/contributing/test.html#run-the-tests

One other thing, it's not necessary to change, but with nosetests the preferred style of writing the tests is slightly different. You can find example tests in the main CKAN codebase, or for example here: https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-dgu/blob/master/ckanext/dgu/tests/functional/test_api.py